# Why can't I build my xCode project after transferring it from one computer to another?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making an app on my dad's computer, and I wanted to transfer it onto my own computer. However, on my own computer, xCode does not let me build the project;it just shows this:

[image]

What does this mean, and what do I do so I can build my app on my phone? Thanks!

Comment: So is this an iOS app? The screenshot is from an OS X project.

Comment: That's the problem. It is an iOS app, but it only shows my mac, and I cannot build it...

Answer (score 0):

Select X-code And Follow screenshot .

[image]